# Simple Product group options

Tags: price, custom-options, group

I have to options size and colour for a simple product.

I want to group some of the options of colour, e.g, reds, greens, blues, and show multiple swatches for each of them.. 3 reds, 4 blues, 2 greens. Each of the reds, blues, greens should share the same price.

Is this possible? Are you aware of any extension that does this?

I don't care about inventory.. products are always on stock.